# Device And Run Icons lost in xcode 7

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode7

I have installed xcode 7 and run many apps on the same. But suddenly when i restart the xcode it hides the device header and run icons in top left bar.[image]

Thanks in advance for help !

Comment: drag your Xcode little you can find

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a exsisting bug with XCode 7 I see on our systems.

It happens when more than one project are open at a time.
The first Window will keep its bar, but all other will open without it. Sometimes hiding/showing the toolbar help, but that works only two times or so. Then a restart of XCode is the only cure.

Comment: Thanks. It works..seems this is bug in xcode 7 itself.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you hid the toolbar. To reenable it: Select `View` -> `Show Toolbar`